# I deployed play framework app to Heroku but it doesn't work

Tags: git, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

**Error Message**

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

**Steps I took**

I downloaded starter project for java from [here](https://www.playframework.com/download#starters) and modified it.

Went to directory of project in cmd and `sbt run`. Application was running correct in `localhost:9000`.

Created new new git repository and pushed the project to it.

Created new heroku app. `heroku create -s cedar`

[image]

Pushed git `git push https://git.heroku.com/safe-stream-24917.git`

[image]

It says Gradle app detected. But documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-support) says that it should say Play app detected. Not sure if that means anything.

[image]

**My play framework project looks like this**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Run this command to force Heroku to use the Scala buildpack:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/scala
```

Your app has both a `build.sbt` and a `build.gradle` so Heroku thinks you want it built with Gradle.

Comment: There's probably nothing wrong with using Gradle for this app, but you'd have to create your own Procfile.

Comment: How do I create a procfile?

Comment: I created a Procfile in the project root and wrote `web: play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS`. Still not working.

Comment: Did you try the Scala buildpack?

Comment: Yes. This time it's detected as play app. But still doesn't work. https://imgur.com/a/IRw97

Comment: This needs to get bubbled up into both heroku's and play's docs. Took a very long time to find. Worked for me, though.

Comment: @KevinGalligan https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/8208